# Wordpress custom widget refreshing issue

Tags: wordpress, widget, themes

I'm using LawyeriaX Lite theme, which contains custom contact widget.

In text fields of that widget, when I'm trying to delete their content, save changes and refresh editing page, content is displayed back on. However, in the frontend everything seems ok - content just disappears. This happens only if I have opened two browser tabs at one moment, even if changes are made only on one of them.

[VIDEO WITH ISSUE](https://youtu.be/LSmAEpl3uJg)

It doesnt matter for me, but client might have problem with that so I'm trying to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Can we have the widget source code ?

**EDIT :**

After check the source code of this widget, I really recommend you to create your own widget into the functions.php file.

This code is currently very complex for nothing.

Just follow this tutorial : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/

Comment: Source code is too long, uploaded it in anonfiles:

https://www.anonfiles.cc/file/5d99e365d23dc2c5b5a1edf1daad62b2

Comment: So i just have to rewrite it in my own way and look if it works?

Comment: Just copy and past the source code of the example here : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/ in your functions.php file. Then add many text fields as you want (taking inspiration from the already existing field: "title")